# Cómo saber todos los parciales sass que se han usado en una página html

Tags: sass

Tengo un sitio muy grande que utiliza muchísimos parciales sass que se preprocesan en un único fichero css. También usamos sourcemaps para debuguear el código css en el navegador.

Quisiera saber si es posible obtener de algún modo una lista de los parciales sass que se están usando en una página html determinada del sitio, para descartar los parciales que no se usan

Muchas gracias

Comment: traduce por favor tu pregunta, estas en la versión en español de SO, bienvenido

Comment: Si la edito, ¿Puedo traducirla yo?

Comment: La traduzco yo, muchas gracias Marco Diaz

Comment: No creo que se pueda analizar la estructura de los SASS per se sin saber dónde se usa o usaría una vez transpilado. Lo que sí puedes hacer es revisar el uso del CSS final en tu o tus páginas usando [UNCSS](https://github.com/uncss/uncss) y luego de obtener la lista de clases no utilizadas, bucear en los SASS para ver dónde se definen esos estilos.

Comment: Gracias @amenadiel! En chrome usando el inspector de elementos gracias a sourcemap tú puedes ver a qué parcial pertenece un selector determinado. A lo mejor hay alguna herramienta que ayude a saber los parciales que se usan para una página ya abierta en el navegador

Comment: Estás usando webpack con un procesador de sass como `node-sass` ? A `node-sass` puedes pasarle la opción `sourceComments: true` para que ponga al principio de cada css de qué sass viene cada bloque. Tal vez combinando eso con UNCSS puedes identificar los estilos no utilizados y luego con los comentarios determinar de qué sass proviene